# Showing hidden phone numbers

Tags: privacy, smartphone

Is there a way to detect a hidden caller ?I always wondered how can you do that.I tried using app like private caller or track call but none of them really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid Caller ID blockers, forward your calls to a 1-800 number (Google Voice can provide these for a small fee) and then to another number. You can't hide/mask/spoof your CID (your ANI) to a 1-800 number. It stems from the olden days of charge-per-minute services that used to be located at 1-800 numbers (before 900 series) but still exists in practice, even if most 1-800 numbers today are free.

[More Info](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/voice/AoEwD7udhAU)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it would be related to paid services (900 series). The whole point of CID towards 1-800 numbers is that the called party is paying, so they should have a right to know who is calling in order to make the decision to pick up the phone and pay.

Comment: TBH I've heard that argument as well and it makes just as much sense to me. In either case, the point is that CID isn't masked toward those numbers for billing purposes. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No. The phone company simply refuses to send you that number.

The police can detect hidden callers though, because the phone company doesn't hide numbers from them. 911 phone lines are fundamentally different from ordinary lines. They even get mobile phone *locations*, not just the numbers.

Comment: But why were hidden numbers created in the first place?what was/is their main purpose?

Comment: The default used to be that all numbers were hidden! You're incorrectly assuming that Calling Line Identification is the standard.

Comment: Ah lol,I didn't even think the default should be "hiding the number"

Comment: @JohnPietrar: The reason this is the "default" is because before there was callerID no caller numbers were viewable by the end user. It requires adding this functionality by all of the phone systems involved. If a caller is calling from a phone system without the ability to provide callerID, that system can't pass the caller number onto your phone provider, and so you can't see it.

Comment: @MarkRipley: I don't think such phone systems are still in service. CID existed by the time the backbones went digital; SS7 definitely supports it.

Comment: @MSalters: There are obsolete phone systems in use in third world countries that don't support callerID. And hackers that use those systems because they know they can't be traced via callerID. Private IDX machines can be set up to report whatever a user wants, or the caller can use a VOIP program that has been altered/hacked to avoid reporting the phone number. My point is that every part of the phone connection has to support callerID, and if any do not, callerID fails, since the caller's number data must pass through every connecting system to reach your callerID device.